# Strongname signing in java?

Tags: java, .net, security, .net-assembly, strongname

In .NET, assemblies can be strongnamed for security purpose. Even the signing process can be delayed until production build. Are there similar feature in java? How jar files are signed?

Comment: [Oracle Official Docs - Signing JAR Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/signing.html)

Comment: Strong naming is not a security feature, and offers almost no security guarantees.

Comment: You can however "seal" a signed jar to avoid shadowing aka mix and match attacks.